# Mapping exception in hibernate with CollectionOfElements

Tags: hibernate, embeddable

I am trying to get this mapping to work, but I get this strange exception message

`Could not determine type for: foo.ProcessUser, at table: ProcessUser_onetimeCodes, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(processUser)]`

```
@Entity
public class ProcessUser {

  @Setter
  private List<OnetimeCodes> onetimeCodes;

  @CollectionOfElements
public List<OnetimeCodes> getOnetimeCodes() {
    return onetimeCodes;
  }
}


@Embeddable
@Data
public class OnetimeCodes {

    @Parent
    private ProcessUser processUser;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;


    public OnetimeCodes(ProcessUser processUser, String password) {
        this.processUser = processUser;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot whats wrong here?
I have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` on `create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error.

You cannot have mapping on the attribute in one of the classes, and on getters on the other. They should match.

So I changed

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class OnetimeCodes {

    @Parent
    private ProcessUser processUser;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;


    public OnetimeCodes(ProcessUser processUser, String password) {
        this.processUser = processUser;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

to

```
@Embeddable
public class OnetimeCodes {

    private ProcessUser processUser;

    private String password;

    public OnetimeCodes(ProcessUser processUser, String password) {
        this.processUser = processUser;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Parent
    public ProcessUser getProcessUser() {
        return processUser;
    }

    public void setProcessUser(ProcessUser processUser) {
        this.processUser = processUser;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and viola. 
Very stupid if you ask me.

Comment: The framework is stupid. I had the very same problem. My setup was so complicated (composite foreign key with many-to-one relation) that I never thought it was that. Not only the code of the framework is bad, but so is the documentation because it never tells you to put `@EmbeddedId` on a getter.